# Uniquely identify elements in Auto Complete List which have similar text using Xpath

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I need to select elements from an auto complete list which appears when you type something on the text field.

I have entered the text "Program NPL"  and following two options show up

LD Program NPL -1  and
Program NPL - 4

I want to choose the second one but cannot use text()='' because the number at last is dynamic and can change in future.

I tried "starts-with" . It works for now but suppose if there is a value like "Program NPL ABC - 4". Then it won't work. Kindly suggest some solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **XPATH** should work

```
//*[starts-with(text(),'Program NPL -')]
```

Comment: This is a really good suggestion . Thank you so much . I'll see how it works